# HTML Tables columns control by php

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination, html-table

I just make a HTML Table and it can control by php codes, but I find problem here, I can not understand why that happen, there is a gap come at first then it start from Database Id numbers, here is my PHP codes,

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
include('connect.php');  



    // Get page data
    $query = "SELECT * FROM profile ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $rs1 = mysql_query($query);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Barat Store Product Profile</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:1294px;
    height:171px;
    z-index:1;
}
#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:174px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:2;
}
#apDiv3 {
    position:absolute;
    left:621px;
    top:107px;
    width:186px;
    height:57px;
    z-index:3;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #F00;
}
#apDiv3 a {
    color: #F00;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="apDiv1">IMAGE</div>
<div id="apDiv2">
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
    <?php
$rs1_endRow = 0;
$rs1_columns = 3; // number of columns
$rs1_hloopRow1 = 1; // first row flag
do {
    if($rs1_endRow == 0  && $rs1_hloopRow1++ != 0) echo "<tr>";
   ?>
<td height="100%"><?php echo $row_rs1['id']; ?><br />
<a href="ASASAS#.php?id=<?php echo $row_rs1['id']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row_rs1['name']; ?><br />
      <img src="#<?php echo $row_rs1['id']; ?>.jpg.jpg" width="400" height="280" />      <br />
    </a></td>
    <?php $rs1_endRow++;
if($rs1_endRow >= $rs1_columns) {
  ?>
  </tr>
  <?php
$rs1_endRow = 0;
  }
} while ($row_rs1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1));
if($rs1_endRow != 0) {
while ($rs1_endRow < $rs1_columns) {
    echo("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
    $rs1_endRow++;
}
echo("</tr>");
}?>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="apDiv3"><a href="page2.php">2nd Page</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my sql code:

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jul 26, 2016 at 11:11 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.5.35

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `probarat`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `profile`
--

CREATE TABLE `profile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `profile`
--

INSERT INTO `profile` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'AMLOKI (INDIAN)'),
(2, 'ANAR DODHI'),
(3, 'AL-VALUKA'),
(4, 'AKARKORA (NUM.1)'),
(5, 'AKARKORA (NUM.2)'),
(6, 'ATMORA'),
(7, 'ANAR DANA'),
(8, 'ADA SOOT (NUM.1)'),
(9, 'AKRABIJ (DORENJO)'),
(10, 'AFTIMUN'),
(11, 'ANJIBAR'),
(12, 'ASHOGONDHA (DESHI)'),
(13, 'ASHOGONDHA (NUM.2)'),
(14, 'ALOYA (MOSABBAR)'),
(15, 'ATUS'),
(16, 'AMLOKI (DESHI)'),
(17, 'AORJUN CHAL'),
(18, 'AL VALU'),
(19, 'ANANTOMUL'),
(20, 'ARBI GUM'),
(21, 'ANARFUL'),
(22, 'BELA GOTA'),
(23, 'BOOJ PATA'),
(24, 'BHAMAN LAL'),
(25, 'BONGSHOLOCHON'),
(26, 'BUCHKI DANA'),
(27, 'B.K KASNI'),
(28, 'BIS FAIJ'),
(29, 'BOHERA'),
(30, 'BIJ LONG'),
(31, 'BADIYAN'),
(32, 'BARENGO SEP'),
(33, 'BUJI DANA'),
(34, 'BABUNA'),
(35, 'BIRONGO DANA'),
(36, 'CHIROTA'),
(37, 'DAIFUL'),
(38, 'DALIM CHALA'),
(39, 'DARHORIDRA'),
(40, 'DARHORIDRA CHAL'),
(41, 'CHAL - MUGORA'),
(42, 'CUNIYA GUM'),
(43, 'FUNDUK'),
(44, 'ISPAGUL HUSK (VUSHI)'),
(45, 'JOIN (ORGINAL)'),
(46, 'GOLAP FUL (NUM.1)'),
(47, 'GOLAP FUL (NUM.2)'),
(48, 'GOR BOCH'),
(49, 'JOISTI MODHU (CUTTING) (NUM.1)'),
(50, 'JOISTI MODHU (REKCIN) (NUM.2)'),
(51, 'JOISTI MODHU (REKCIN) (NUM.3)'),
(52, 'HORTOKI JUNGLI'),
(53, 'HENA JAL (30KG)/ (50KG)'),
(54, 'GOKUR KATA'),
(55, 'HING'),
(56, 'GUGUL (INDIA)'),
(57, 'GUGUL (PAKISTANI)'),
(58, 'GAOJABON'),
(59, 'HORTUKI'),
(60, 'GORMAR BOTI/PATA'),
(61, 'JOHORMOHRA'),
(62, 'JAMAL GOTA'),
(63, 'JOTAMANSHI (NUM.1)'),
(64, 'GULE JUFA'),
(65, 'INDROJOB RED'),
(66, 'KUTKI'),
(67, 'KAKRASHING'),
(68, 'LOCHCHAL'),
(69, 'KUCHILA'),
(70, 'KHOSH'),
(71, 'KHORASANI JOIN'),
(72, 'LAL CHONDON'),
(73, 'KATILA (NUM.1)'),
(74, 'KATILA (NUM.2)'),
(75, 'KATILA (NUM.3)'),
(76, 'KUNDOR'),
(77, 'KALO MEGH'),
(78, 'KALO DANA'),
(79, 'LAL DANA'),
(80, 'KUMKUM'),
(81, 'KATILA CUTTING'),
(82, 'METHI (INDIA)'),
(83, 'METHI (DESHI)'),
(84, 'MAJUFOL (GREEN)'),
(85, 'MAJUFOL (WHITE)'),
(86, 'MARJAN'),
(87, 'MONJESTA'),
(88, 'MOHURI'),
(89, 'MAKU DANA'),
(90, 'MOTA BOCH'),
(91, 'MEHEDI PATA'),
(92, 'NEPALI KHOR (RAKCIN)'),
(93, 'NAGOR MOTHA'),
(94, 'PARSUSA'),
(95, 'PIPUL (CHOTO DANA)'),
(96, 'PIPUL (GOL DANA)'),
(97, 'PIPUL (S.P INDIAN)'),
(98, 'RITHA (NUM.1)'),
(99, 'REWCHINI'),
(100, 'ROTON JUT'),
(101, 'TOKME ISPAST'),
(102, 'SONAPATA'),
(103, 'SAHI JIRA'),
(104, 'SOYLOJ'),
(105, 'SADA KORI'),
(106, 'TOKME KHATMI'),
(107, 'TOKME KHOBBAJI'),
(108, 'TOKME KASHNI'),
(109, 'SUNRISE KHOR'),
(110, 'SADA CHONDON'),
(111, 'TOKME KARAF'),
(112, 'TOKME HAMMAJ'),
(113, 'SAPISTAN'),
(114, 'SILAJEET'),
(115, 'SALEM GOTA'),
(116, 'SAKAKUL MISRI'),
(117, 'TOP CHINI'),
(118, 'TOJ (LALUKA)'),
(119, 'SURONJON'),
(120, 'TAL MAKHNA (INDIAN)'),
(121, 'TAL MAKHNA (DESHI)'),
(122, 'TOKMA (KALA TULSI)'),
(123, 'THANKUNI PATA'),
(124, 'SURMA KALO'),
(125, 'SURMA SADA'),
(126, 'TOKME KASUS'),
(127, 'S.K.F KHOR'),
(128, 'SORNOLOTA'),
(129, 'SIMUL MUL'),
(130, 'UDE KUDDUS'),
(131, 'UDE SALIB'),
(132, 'UNNAB'),
(133, 'ISABGUL DANA'),
(134, 'KAKULI'),
(135, 'TOKME KHAKSI'),
(136, 'TOKME ISPAK');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `profile`
--
ALTER TABLE `profile`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

This is my result photo:

[image]

Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You get it because you told it to be output:

```
do {
    if($rs1_endRow == 0  && $rs1_hloopRow1++ != 0) echo "<tr>";
   ?>
<td height="100%"><?php echo $row_rs1['id']; ?><br />
                                 ^^^^---undefined
    [..snip...]
} while ($row_rs1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1));
           ^---until this executes
```

Since `$row_rs1` doesn't get set until AFTER the first iteration of your do/while loop, you output a bunch of undefined variables.

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: I can not understand, what should I change? please help?

Answer (score -1):

Look at this line: `<img src="#<?php echo $row_rs1['id']; ?>.jpg.jpg" width="400" height="280" />`

Make sure that the image path is correct, and I doubt that you have **".jpg.jpg"**.

Use "Inspector" from your browser to ensure the image link is correct.

Comment: sir that was not a big problem.

Comment: This isn't image problem, its a problem from php codes,,,,